# find uppercase algorithem

Tags: python, algorithm, uppercase

I'm trying to find the first uppercase letter in a given string, I tried this code

```
def recursive_find_algorithem(str):
    if str[0].isupper():
        return str[0]
    else:
        try:
            recursive_find_algorithem(str[1:])
        except IndexError:
            return "no uppercase found"
```

but it works only when the uppercase letter is the first letter and returns "None" otherwise

Comment: `return recursive_find_algorithem(str[1:])`

Comment: @Barmar FYI there is a canonical Python question for this problem.